# How to select a text from a class to fit the with of the div?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Based on the following code I want to know how can I select the biggest text that fits in the width I define in CSS?

Now it is showing all texts but is showing only 200px of the text because this is what I've defined.

In future I will have a XML file where I have multiple texts and I thing by AJAX call I will read that file.

https://jsfiddle.net/a06cu92t/

```
$(".places").each(function (index, item) {
    var obj = $(item).find("span");
    if (obj.length) {
        var placename = $(obj).text();
        if ($(obj).width() > $(item).width() && placename.trim().length > 0) {
            var limit = 0;
            do {
                limit++;
                placename = placename.substring(0, placename.length - 1);
                $(obj).text(placename + "...");
            } while ($(obj).width() > $(item).width() && limit < 1000)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you use css `text-overflow: ellipsis` and save all js lines and make it better performance and cleaner??

Comment: I'm confused by your question and by the fiddle.  What exactly do you want it to do that it's not already doing?

Comment: For example I have a container 300x250 and multiple texts. The width of  text in one line is different smaller than 300px or bigger. And I want to calculate the width of my texts and then show only the text that fits in 300px. As in my JSFiddle you can see that first text is smaller than 200px but in the same time it fits the second sext properly. And third text doesn't. In this case it should show only second text.

Comment: That you try to achieve is dangerous and very weird. The text will render different between browsers and operating systems. This means that you need to make a script for each browser for each operating system you want. You will not obtain a perfect width from a text that fits in 200 pixels between browsers. Maybe you obtain a 200.34555 pixels and this means that fits, but you must control all of this. If you was me, I don't like and don't want to make things like this.

Answer (score 2):

As a suggestion, I don't know why you need all these lines of javascript when CSS have `text-overflow` property to make the same:

```css
.overflow {
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow">
  A long text like this and all without javascript!
</div>
```

Comment: read my comment from above and you will understand why I use JS to define this.

Comment: Maybe you must to explain by this mode in the post, not in a comment. However I put a comment to you that's very true. You will have tons of problems and weird behaviours with what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to automatically break the words and show dots where the content is overflowing. Luckily for you, you can just achieve this by using css, so you don't have to do this kind of scripting.

You should use it like this:

```
div.places {
  width : 200px;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[I've updated your jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/a06cu92t/1/)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you ONLY want to show the line of text that is the longest in length, but that also fits within the 200px width of the box. Is that right? So in your jsfiddle, the ONLY line of text that would show would be the second one because it is the longest line of text that doesn't extend past the width of the box. Yes?

Comment: @StephanieKendall Thats true. This is what I want

Comment: Ok, now I understand, please see my other answer for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by using offsetWidth and some jquery help, like this:

```
var longestElement, longestWidth = 0;
$(".places span").each(function (index, span) {

    if ($(span).length) {
        var width = span.offsetWidth;
        if (width > longestWidth && width < 200) {
          longestElement = span;
          longestWidth = width;
        }
    }
    $(span).hide();
});

$(longestElement).show();
```

I've updated the [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/a06cu92t/4/)